# The selected boot device failed. Press any key to continue

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, dell-xps

I am attempting to create a bootable USB drive to install Windows LTSB on my computer.  To do so I have taken the following steps.

1) Procured an ISO file containing Windows LTSB

2) Tested that this ISO file worked by a] verifying its checksum and b] opening it with Virtualbox

3) Use Rufus to create a bootable USB drive like so:

[image: Screenshot_Of_Rufus]

4) Launch UEFI and change the following settings (the following is not exact wording):

- Secure boot to off
- "Legacy boot" to on or off (either option didn't work)
- "Allow legacy ROMs to on"

I would then re-launch my computer and press F12 to select a bootable drive. While I could select a bootable drive labeled as "Mass Media Storage Device" - it would not launch and instead would give the error described in the post title.

How can I fix this error, or at the very least, determine if the problem is with my UEFI settings or flashdrive?

Comment: If it helps, the only time I ever got that error when when I tried to make a bootable Windows 8.1 USB drive from Linux. (Linux cannot create Windows bootable media)

Answer (score 1):

The two links are about how to create windows 10 bootable USB flash drive step by step, we can refer the detailed descriptions and video in them.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-rufus-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive-to-install-almost-any-os/

https://softwarebakery.com/using-rufus-to-create-bootable-usb-images

In addition, we can also create a bootable USB drive by Microsoft official tool——[Windows USB/DVD Download Tool.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485)

1. Download the MSDN version of Win10 ISO image file and Windows USB/DVD Download Tool software;
2. Install and run the Windows USB / DVD Download Tool, load the downloaded Win10 ISO image file, click "Next";
3. Select "USB device" about media type;
4. Select your USB device (U disk). If the USB flash disk is not recognized, click the refresh button, after confirming the USB flash disk, click “Begin copying” to start copying. (Note: If you need to burn the boot CD, please select “DVD” mode. ).
5. At this point, the U disk boot disk is finished, restart the computer and boot from the U disk.

Remarks: Since this method is a pure version of the U disk installation boot disk, it will not integrate various software and drivers. It is recommended to download the relevant drivers in advance for use! (especially the network card driver, after installing the system, only the network can be guaranteed to install other drivers.)

Answer (score 0):

Burn the USB drive in MBR Partition scheme and try..

Comment: It might be worth mentioning when this helps - since not all computers are happy to boot in UEFI mode, and for some reason I'm remembering you need MBR for a fat32 installer but I may be wrong